# Understanding String Immutability in Java

Tags: java

While trying the understand the reasons behind why strings are immutable, I wrote a simple program as follows:

```
/* Program to test string immutability */

public class StringImmutability
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = "hello";
        s.concat(" world"); // returns a new string object. So, the reference must point to this object for further processing like this: s = s.concat(" world");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.concat(" world");
        System.out.println(s);
        String s1 = s, s2 = s, s3 = s;
        System.out.println(s1+" "+s2+" "+s3);
        s = s.concat(" test");
        //The references are modified
        System.out.println(s1+" "+s2+" "+s3); 
    }
}
```

The output though isn't as expected:

```
hello
hello world
hello world hello world hello world
hello world hello world hello world
```

After the references are modified, the output must be `hello world test` repeated thrice but there isn't any change in output.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is working exactly as expected. Let's look at it step by step:

```
String s = "hello";
s.concat(" world");
```

[image]

This is effectively a NOP because you are not assigning the result of `concat` to anything. That new `String` instance is lost to the ether and garbage collected since there is nothing referring to it. Hence, your `s` remains unchanged.

```
s = s.concat(" world");
```

[image]

Here `s.concat(" world")` returns a new `String` instance, and you have reassigned `s` to that. So `s` now points to this *new* string and you have lost the reference to the older one (the one that just had `hello` in it).

```
String s1 = s, s2 = s, s3 = s;
```

[image]

Here you have created three variables that all point to the same string instance that `s` points to.

```
s = s.concat(" test");
```

[image]

This is a repeat of what you did earlier. `concat` creates a new string instance and you reassign `s` to that. But keep in mind that `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are still pointing to what `s` *used to* point to and so they will **not** reflect the changes.

You've only stopped `s` from pointing to the old string and made it point to the new one. But your other variables are still pointing to that old string.

Comment: Did you already have those images lying around waiting for exactly this question?! What other pre-made illustration do you have!?

Comment: @Lii I used a program called yEd to draw those. It is very easy to make illustrations like the ones above using yEd.

Answer (score 7):

Your code proves String immutability. You can change the String that a variable refers to, but you can't change the String object itself (other than through shifty reflection tricks that I won't discuss here). The error above is in your expected output and nothing else. For example,

```
s = s.concat(" test");
```

creates a **new** String object and assigns it to the `s` variable. It does not and cannot change the original object that `s` referred to.

Answer (score 6):

`s` is reassigned to a new string that has the `" test"` `String` appended to the end of the target `String` value (`s` pre-assignment).

```
s = s.concat(" test");
```

This does not affect the `String` value stored in `s1`, `s2`, or `s3`, since `concat` returns a new `String` object.